# Реализация select с датой рождения

Tags: html, css

Возможно ли реализовать такую форму на html и css? Я вижу только вариант где делаешь 3 селекта, но тогда такой огромный список со значениями будет, наверняка есть альтернативные варианты. инпут с типой date не подходит.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вариант с 3 селектами и есть самый лучший, никак иначе вы не сделаете

Comment: а как нибудь сделать код короче есть возможность?

Comment: я не видел вашего кода, откуда я могу знать? вообще тут все элементарно

Comment: <select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>

Comment: и тд получается список значений из 30-31 дня потом список из 12 и с годами тоже не маленький

Comment: никак иначе вы не сделаете

Comment: ок понял спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать например с помощью компонента DatePicker, вот тут хороший пример: https://codepen.io/ranjith555/pen/OyKjjm

```
$('.date').datepicker({
  multidate: true,
    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
});
```